# ReflectionException since upgrading to PHP 7.2

Tags: craft3, php

I've today upgraded from PHP 5.6 to 7.2 so that I could upgrade to Craft 3.0.

After needing to install a lot of updates, the craft server check is completely green and says everything should be fine.

However, I'm getting the following issue despite correct settings in the .env file. I've checked that the user/pass works for the mysql database and it all seems fine.

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
ReflectionException: Class craft\db\mysql\Schema does not exist in /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:428
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(428): ReflectionClass->__construct('craft\\db\\mysql\\...')
#1 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(364): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('craft\\db\\mysql\\...')
#2 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\db\\mysql\\...', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\db\\mysql\\...', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(824): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#5 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/Connection.php(341): yii\db\Connection->getSchema()
#6 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(223): craft\db\Connection->tableExists('{{%info}}', false)
#7 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Sites.php(1001): craft\web\Application->getIsInstalled()
#8 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Sites.php(380): craft\services\Sites->_loadAllSites()
#9 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(180): craft\services\Sites->setCurrentSite(NULL)
#10 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(546): yii\base\Component->__set('currentSite', NULL)
#11 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(craft\services\Sites), Array)
#12 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#13 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(383): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#14 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\services\\...', Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\services\\...', Array, Array)
#16 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#17 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('sites', true)
#18 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(289): yii\base\Module->get('sites', true)
#19 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(983): craft\web\Application->get('sites')
#20 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Request.php(914): craft\web\Application->getSites()
#21 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Request.php(161): craft\web\Request->_getCurrentSite()
#22 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Request->init()
#23 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#24 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(383): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#25 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#26 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#27 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/app.web.php(41): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#28 [internal function]: {closure}()
#29 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(503): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#30 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(351): yii\di\Container->invoke(Object(Closure), Array)
#31 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Object(Closure))
#32 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('request', true)
#33 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(289): yii\base\Module->get('request', true)
#34 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(74): craft\web\Application->get('request')
#35 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(499): yii\di\ServiceLocator->__get('request')
#36 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(115): yii\web\ErrorHandler->shouldRenderSimpleHtml()
#37 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(156): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException))
#38 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): craft\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException))
#39 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(71): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException))
#40 [internal function]: craft\web\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException))
#41 {main}
Previous exception:
yii\base\ErrorException: include(/var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/composer/../craftcms/cms/src/db/mysql/Schema.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(84): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'include(/var/ww...', '/var/www/shaneh...', 444)
#1 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): craft\web\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'include(/var/ww...', '/var/www/shaneh...', 444, Array)
#2 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#3 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/shaneh...')
#4 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('craft\\db\\mysql\\...')
#5 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('craft\\db\\mysql\\...')
#6 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(428): ReflectionClass->__construct('craft\\db\\mysql\\...')
#7 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(364): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('craft\\db\\mysql\\...')
#8 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\db\\mysql\\...', Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\db\\mysql\\...', Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(824): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#11 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/Connection.php(341): yii\db\Connection->getSchema()
#12 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(223): craft\db\Connection->tableExists('{{%info}}', false)
#13 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Sites.php(1001): craft\web\Application->getIsInstalled()
#14 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Sites.php(380): craft\services\Sites->_loadAllSites()
#15 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(180): craft\services\Sites->setCurrentSite(NULL)
#16 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(546): yii\base\Component->__set('currentSite', NULL)
#17 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(craft\services\Sites), Array)
#18 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#19 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(383): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#20 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\services\\...', Array, Array)
#21 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\services\\...', Array, Array)
#22 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#23 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('sites', true)
#24 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(289): yii\base\Module->get('sites', true)
#25 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(983): craft\web\Application->get('sites')
#26 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Request.php(914): craft\web\Application->getSites()
#27 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Request.php(161): craft\web\Request->_getCurrentSite()
#28 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Request->init()
#29 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#30 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(383): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#31 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#32 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#33 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/app.web.php(41): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#34 [internal function]: {closure}()
#35 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(503): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#36 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(351): yii\di\Container->invoke(Object(Closure), Array)
#37 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Object(Closure))
#38 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('request', true)
#39 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(289): yii\base\Module->get('request', true)
#40 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(160): craft\web\Application->get('request')
#41 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(104): yii\web\Application->getRequest()
#42 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(273): craft\web\Application->bootstrap()
#43 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(90): yii\base\Application->init()
#44 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Application->init()
#45 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(206): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#46 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(82): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#47 [internal function]: craft\web\Application->__construct(Array)
#48 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(383): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#49 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\web\\Appli...', Array, Array)
#50 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\web\\Appli...', Array, Array)
#51 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php(249): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#52 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php(42): require('/var/www/shaneh...')
#53 /var/www/shanehudson.net/codebase/craft/web/index.php(20): require('/var/www/shaneh...')
#54 {main}
```

Comment: Note: I had this installation working fine on local machine and uploaded to git. So do I have to reinstall it manually?

Comment: Also, I'm running it with nginx and php7.2-fpm.

Comment: Did you check if the file exists?

Comment: Hmm. I checked the ClassLoader but not the mysql. Does look like vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/mysql/ folder is missing

Comment: You should do a composer update if this does not work, delete your vendor folder and try it again

Comment: Yeah looks like I had some missing files, thanks! Now just need to figure out why the database migrations fail heh